# Escape colon in Reactive Search field name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, reactive, reactivesearch

I am testing a very basic [reactive search](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/) implementation.

My code is as below:
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { ReactiveBase, DataSearch, ResultCard } from '@appbaseio/reactivesearch';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>

        <ReactiveBase
            app="indexName"
            url="https://someurl.amazonaws.com"
          >

          <DataSearch
            componentId="SearchSensor"
            dataField={ "field_product:title" }
            autoSuggest={true}
          />    

          <ResultCard
             componentId="results"
             dataField="field_product"
             react={{
               "and": ["SearchSensor"]
             }}
             onData={(res)=>({
               "image": res.image,
               "title": res.field_product:title,
               "description":   res.description
             })}
           />

          </ReactiveBase>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

My fields in index look somewhat as below:

```
{
  "_index": "kirana11",
  "_type": "product_autocomplete",
  "_id": "66641",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 66641,
    "description": "Some Nestle Product ",
    "field_product:title": "Nestle Product",    
    "field_product:commerce_price:amount": 83
}
```

In the above example, when I call fields like `res.image` it works flawlessly. However, fields like `field_product:title` & `field_product:commerce_price:amount` returns an error as below:

> Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected, (34:41)

What is the right way to access fields with a colon in it? Is there a way to escape it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it around quotes and use bracket instead of dot notation to access the property:

```
res['field_product:title']
```

This is also how you would access a property using a variable:

```
const key = 'field_product:title';
res[key]
```

It might be better to change your json structure though:

```
fieldProduct: {
  title: '',
  commercePrice: ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. The indexing part is done from a different application where I have no control. Hence, there is sadly nothing I can do about the JSON structure.